# Is it possible to change the height on a jquery ui progressbar

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, progress-bar, jquery-ui-progressbar

I have a progress bar in a html table cell.  It seems to expand to the width of the table cell but i want to explicitly specify the height of the progress bar.

Is it possible to specify the height of a jQuery progress bar?

```
    $(this).progressbar({
        value: parseInt($(this).attr("rel"))
    });
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Of course it is. There's even a [resizable progress bar demo](http://jqueryui.com/demos/progressbar/#resize).

Too fancy for you? Just use [`.height()`](http://api.jquery.com/height):

```
$('#progressbar').height(400);
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/N5AVv/

Comment: i don't want my users to change the size.  i want to specific the height programatically.  i don't see this option

Comment: then just use height - that's the programmatic option

Comment: Not working for me. The jsfiddle demo gives empty result. Also on my webpage the progress right bottom is cut

Comment: @g.pickardou apologies, a link rotted. Fixed.

Answer (score 2):

you can also use this function which works for all css attribures

```
$("#progressbar" ).css( "maxWidth", "200%" );
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need to edit the jQuery UI CSS file.  It will look something like

```
jquery-ui-1.8.17.custom.css
```

Scroll to the bottom (~line 564) and your will see the following CSS attribute:

```
.ui-progressbar (...);
```

change the HEIGHT attribute value to whatever you want, save the file and upload it to your server.  Refresh your browser and you have your customized progress bar.